# Is it possible to call only one line out from function?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

```
NpgsqlCommand upCmd = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE Masina SET nosaukums=@nosaukums,svars=@svars,marka=@marka,modelis=@modelis,sedvietas=@sedvietas WHERE ID=@id", ncon);
Parametri(upCmd);

NpgsqlCommand addCmd = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO Masina (id,nosaukums,svars,marka,modelis,sedvietas) VALUES(@id,@nosaukums,@svars,@marka,@modelis,@sedvietas)", ncon);
Parametri(addCmd);

NpgsqlCommand delCmd = new NpgsqlCommand("DELETE FROM Masina WHERE id=@id", ncon);
delCmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "id"));
```

I made function `Parametri` for `upCmd` and `addCmd` because they have exactly same lines. Could I use the same function for `delCmd` also? Is it possible to call only one line for deleting?

Something like `Parametri(delCmd, *call only id*);`

Parametri() code:

```
static void Parametri(NpgsqlCommand cmd)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "id"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@nosaukums", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 255, "nosaukums"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@svars", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "svars"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@marka", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 255, "marka"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@modelis", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "modelis"));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@sedvietas", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "sedvietas"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to add a param to the function, which you could use to determine if the function should add all the parameters, or just the ID parameter.

something like

```
static void Parametri(NpgsqlCommand cmd, bool justId)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "id"));
        if(justId){return;}
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@nosaukums", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 255, "nosaukums"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@svars", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "svars"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@marka", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 255, "marka"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@modelis", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "modelis"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@sedvietas", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "sedvietas"));
    }
```

EDIT:

You could use an optional parameter to avoid having to pass a bool in for each call:

```
static void Parametri(NpgsqlCommand cmd, bool justId = false)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@id", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "id"));
        if(justId){return;}
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@nosaukums", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 255, "nosaukums"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@svars", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "svars"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@marka", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 255, "marka"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@modelis", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "modelis"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@sedvietas", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "sedvietas"));
    }
```

You could then call the function with

```
Parametri(upCmd);
Parametri(addCmd);
Parametri(delCmd, true);
```

Comment: Parametri(upCmd, false); Parametri(addCmd, false); Parametri(delCmd, true); do i have to write it like this to call all of them now?

Comment: yep, that should do it.

Comment: @RobertsŠensters addd an edit which gets you away from having to pass false on your add and update commands.